# Why is one of my TFS projects not visible from Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops

I have (very) recently began setting up a few TFS projects. I successfully set up two a couple of days ago, which are visible from Visual Studio 2013's Team Explorer, beneath bla.visualstudio.com

I added a third one today, and I can see all three at the link for them (https://bla.visualstudio.com/_projects).

Why does the third/newest project not display in Visual Studio?

I refreshed Team Explorer, and that made no difference. I even restarted Visual Studio, and still no difference.

The next thing I need to do is map the new project to its local source code, but I can't do that without their being a visible representation of the TFS project in Team Explorer.

What must I do yet to get the new project, which is visible "in the cloud" to also be visible in Visual Studio?

Comment: Do you get the same issue in Visual Studio 2015 or 2017?

Comment: When you say team explorer, did you mean the project is missing in the solution explorer or source control explorer ?

Comment: Can you put in a screenshot of the place where you would expect the new project to show up? Have you tried to add the project through "Manage Connections" --> "Connect to Team Project" in the "Team Explorer" window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add the project (as a visible one), from the `Connect to Team Foundation Server` dialog. You find it by clicking the green plug icon in the top of the Team Explorer and then pressing `Manage Connections`.

[image: Connect to Team Doundation Server dialog]

Since the project was now created yet, when you first added the server connection, it could not be selected at that point.

Comment: Although the dialogues are different, the idea is the same for Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0):

First right clicking on the solution and getting the newest version, usually  this should add the missing project

Then please check if the missing project is showing under the Source Control Explorer.

If there are ,doing a manually map with local code or get down in another folder.

[image]

Another solution is using **"Add existing project"** in solution explorer which may do the trick. Detail steps please refer the answer in this similar question: [Solution explorer not updating team projects in Visual Studio 2015](https://superuser.com/questions/981038/solution-explorer-not-updating-team-projects-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: This is not an answer to the question. The question is about team projects in VSTS, not adding projects in Visual Studio.