# How do I add the source code to a TFS project in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfs, azure-devops, source-control-explorer

I've got projects added to TFS in Visual Studio, with some help from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42238659/why-is-one-of-my-tfs-projects-not-visible-from-visual-studio).

Now I need to add the source code (which has already been mapped, which I would think would be all that was necessary), but the project ("Report Runner") does not show the code (as "RoboReporterDataFilesGeneratorUtil" does, but I don't recall now how I got that to work).

This is what I see when I right-click "Report Runner"

[image]

When I select "Get Latest Version" says that all files are up-to-date

When I select "Check Out for Edit..." it seems to churn and choogle awhile, but even a refresh shows no addition to the contents below Report Runner

When I select "Check In Pending Changes", I see this below Team Explorer:

[image]

Selecting the "Check In" button invokes a dialog "Continue to check-in 5 items?"

Selecting "Yes" results in the following message below "Pending Changes" in Team Explorer:

"All of the changes were either unmodified files or locks. The changes have been undone by the server."

When I select "Advanced > Get Specific Version", I see this:

[image]

...but selecting "Get" there tells me, "All files are up to date. No files were updated... To force an update, use the "Get Specific Version" command with the "Overwrite all..." option checked."

But even doing that works no wonders, miracles, or even anything at all, mundane or otherwise.

So how do I add the source code from the local project so that it displays in Source Control Explorer?

### UPDATE

I dragged (drug?) the source folder to C:\Users\cshannon\Source\Workspaces\ReportRunner, but failed to COPY it; it moved it, so that the source was no longer in its original place. I had to copy it back over from the users folder to its original location. However, that makes no difference - the current state of the TFS project is still exactly the same as delineated above.

NOTE: It does so "move" (rather than copy) in the official docs [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/share-your-code-in-tfvc-vs#workspace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "Add the files to Source Control".

You can do this by:

1. Opening the Solution in Visual Studio, then right-clicking on the solution and selecting "Add Solution to Source Control" - This will miss any files that are not part of the solution.
2. Open Seouce Explorer, navigate to the mapped folder, and right-click in the empty space and select "Add files"

The #2 is the preferred option and will get all of the files in. Look out for files that you want to be check in ending up in the "exclusions" list...

Comment: I tried the "Add Files" (I tried everything), and it didn't work. #1 worked for me, though.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add the solution from the Solution Explorer - it doesn't seem it can all be done from the Team Explorer. So, I right-clicked the solution, selected "Add Solution to Source Control...", then "Check in..." and now the files are there in Source Control Explorer as part of the visualstudio.com meangerie.

Either I did something wrong to begin with, or this is an awfully convoluted, clunky, and possibly even kludgy way to get VS to work with TFS.

Why can't you just right-click a project and select "Create a TFS project"? Or be able to do it all from TFS? Again, this setting up of projects in TFS, copying the source over via Windows Explorer, and then making yet another step in Visual Studio seems nerdily gawky and macabre to me.

Unless (quite likely) I goofed it all up somewhere along the line. In any case, though, it could be a lot smoother. Just writin'.